# Jquery: hide slider when checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am trying to hide some `input` fields when a `checkbox` is clicked.

Currently the `checkbox` will change color when clicked so that i know which one is active. It is not hiding the field when clicked tho.

I've tried a few methods but none seem to work so any help would be great.

My JQuery code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#approvedToggle").buttonset(function () {
        if ($('#ApproveButton').prop('checked')) {
            $("#slider2").show();
        } else {
            $("#slider2").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

My asp.net markup

```
<div class="price-slider">
     <h4 class="great">Do you pay an annual renewal fee?</h4>

    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div>
            <fieldset id="approvedToggle" class="text-center">
                <input type="radio" id="ApproveButton" checked="checked" name="radio" />
                <label id="ApproveButtonLabel" for="ApproveButton">Yes</label>
                <input type="radio" id="RejectButton" name="radio" />
                <label id="RejectButtonLabel" for="RejectButton">No</label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <p class="text-center">Percentage amount</p>
        <div id="slider2"></div>
         <h2 class="text-center" style="color: red"><b>OR</b></h2>

        <p class="text-center">Fixed Amount</p>
        <input type="text" id="fixedAnnualy" placeholder="0" class="form-control" />
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
#ApproveButtonLabel.ui-state-active {
    background: blue;
}
#ApproveButtonLabel.ui-state-active span.ui-button-text {
    color: White;
    font: bold
}
#RejectButtonLabel.ui-state-active {
    background: blue;
}
#RejectButtonLabel.ui-state-active span.ui-button-text {
    color: White;
    font: bold
}
```

Comment: your div is empty `<div id="slider2"></div>`

Comment: `$("#approvedToggle").buttonset().change(function () {` try with this.

Comment: no idea how to make a jsfiddle am not to good with JS as it is :( and i the code for the slider adds itself using css and jquery

Comment: Here is a fiddle, with your code, for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Un88c/

Comment: Jai add that as a descriptive answer and i will give you the tick as yours worked :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

you need to change event action and need to change html:

```
<div id="slider2"></div>
```

your `$("#slider2")` is empty.

```
$(function () {
            $("#approvedToggle input[type='radio']").click(function () {
                if ($('#ApproveButton').prop('checked')) {
                    $("#slider2").show();
                } else {
                    $("#slider2").hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

<kbd>[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Un88c/3/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below and take a look at [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xhngx/20/)

```
      $("#approvedToggle").click(function ()  {
          if ($('#ApproveButton').prop('checked')) {
              $("#slider2").show();
          } else {
              $("#slider2").hide();
          }
       });
```

Your slider2 was empty so added a simple data .

Check if this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Bind the event separately from invoking the buttonset

```
$("#approvedToggle").buttonset();

           $("#approvedToggle").change(function () {
              if ($('#ApproveButton').prop('checked')) {
                  $("#slider2").show();
              } else {
                  $("#slider2").hide();
              }
           });
```